# Unique keys are automatically indexed in MySQL - is it true?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with about 200k rows:

```
 CREATE TABLE `yaThread` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `yaid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `complete` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `version` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
   `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `info` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `stCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `yaidk` (`yaid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=510312 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have suddenly found that my on "yaid" queries are rather slow - it seems that they are not indexed - is it really true?

---

Here are some simple tests.

PRIMARY KEY

```
 mysql> select * from yaThread where id = 12999993
     -> ;
 Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

UNIQUE

```
 mysql> select * from yaThread where yaid = 123;
 Empty set (2.33 sec)
 mysql> select * from yaThread where yaid = 124;
 Empty set (0.96 sec)
```

NON KEY FIELD

```
 mysql> select * from yaThread where info = 123;
 Empty set (0.46 sec)
```

Comment: `UNIQUE KEY` inside a table definition is a synonym for `create unique index on ...` outside of the table definition. [From the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) "*KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX*"

Comment: means this that UNIQUE KEYS are build as BTREE idnexes and should be fast for searching ?

Comment: Yes. As I said: declaring a `unique key` (or simply `key` ) is the same as creating an index. It's just a shorthand notation.

Comment: @OlegGolovanov unique keys would normally default to hashes, no need for b-trees.

Comment: I think so. But it does not explain why UNIQUE field selects are much mor slower than PRIMARY KEY and comparable with non indexed field searching .

Comment: PRIMARY keys are used by the UNIQUE keys (and every other index) to reference a row. It's natural that UNIQUE keys would be (marginally) slower than PRIMARY because both indexes need to be read and intersected.

Comment: But by your tests I see the primary key being fetched in 0.00 time. Disable your query cache and you'll see the "real" time it took to fetch one row by PRIMARY key. And compare it to the UNIQUE after that.  You'll notice the difference is marginal as I said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Yes, they have to be, otherwise the uniqueness constraint could not be upheld.

### Background info:

In order to ensure uniqueness an `INDEX` is created for the `UNIQUE` column(s) perhaps using type `HASH`.

Hashtables and hashtrees are structures which digest a key and the outputted result is a number (usually in hex notation but still just a number). That number is usually "unique" to that key. Because of this it is easy to store a small amount of data (ex.: 16bytes) based on whatever length input (1024bytes varchar).

Most hashtable implementations allow duplicates for a particular key (or in the unlikely event that the different keys have the same hash).

The implementation of SQL indexes is on disk hastables or on disk b-trees (with variations on the subject).

PRIMARY keys reference the actual disk block + offset within the block. UNIQUE keys reference a PRIMARY key.

Essentially PRIMARY keys are used by the UNIQUE keys (and every other index) to reference a row. It's natural that UNIQUE keys would be (marginally) slower than PRIMARY because both indexes need to be read and intersected to find a disk block and offset.

### Sidenote:

Primary keys are also unique keys themselves and they are also indexed automatically because of being declared `PRIMARY`.

Comment: *Yes, they have to be, otherwise the uniqueness constraint could not be upheld.* Well, technically they could be upheld. Just really slowly.

Comment: There's a CSV storage engine which keeps the entire table data inside a CSV file. CSV engine does not have any types of indexes or constraints. Not sure if you can define PRIMARY / UNIQUE. I'm pretty sure the functionality relies on there being an index available.